# Turn all textboxes into WYSIWYG HTML Editors using PageMod

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, textarea, firefox-addon-sdk, nicedit

I am trying to create an addon that turns all textareas on certain pages into WYSIWYG HTML editors. I tried using [PageMod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) by calling the NicEdit library and then running a content script with the code to turn all textareas into NicEdit editors. Here is the code I am trying to use:

main.js:

```
// Import the APIs
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var self = require("self");

// Create a page mod
// It will run a script whenever a URL is loaded
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("nicEdit-latest.js"),
                      self.data.url("pagedit.js")]
});
```

pagedit.js

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);
```

And then NicEdit-latest.js is just the NicEdit lirbrary.

I saved and installed the addon and tried to load W3Schools' [demo on textareas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/showit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea), but the textarea still looked like a normal textarea.

Comment: So, what doesn't work? Do you see any error, is there some other issue? Please edit the question and add that information.

Comment: To get errors, open the error console at Tools / Web Developer / Error Console

Comment: I created a test page that just contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<textarea>test textarea</textarea>`, and no errors show up when I load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The content scripts were firing at the wrong time. I fixed it by adding
     contentScriptWhen: 'start',
between the `include` and the `ContentScriptFile`.